# How to get count of multidimentional array with conditions in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have mongo document chatMessages as

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5784dcd9db2c60b54b8b45d3"),
    "sender_id" : "55505ad6b5a0925f4c8b7707",
    "receivers_id" : [
        "57715368db2c60e5208b4579"
    ],
    "messages" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5784e0fadb2c605c6d8b4578"),
            "sender" : "57715368db2c60e5208b4579",
            "message" : "hai",
            "send_at" : NumberLong(1468326138),
            "read_by" : [
                {
                    "user" : "55505ad6b5a0925f4c8b7707",
                    "at" : NumberLong(0)
                }
            ]
        }       
    ],
    "updated_at" : NumberLong(1468327157),
    "created_at" : NumberLong(1468327157)
}
```

I need to find a total unread messages from the document above. 
Suppose my current user_id is `55505ad6b5a0925f4c8b7707`. I have been stuck somewhere to get results. So help me guys

> Update

```
$unread_messages = ChatMessages::find([
        'conditions' => [
            '$or' => [
                ['sender_id' => $user_id],
                ['receivers_id' => ['$elemMatch' => ['$eq' => $user_id]]]
            ],
            'messages.sender' => ['$ne' => $user_id]
        ]
    ]);
```

first this query should have shown some results but i am receiving null value

Comment: Can you show us where you are getting stuck?

Comment: @chridam you can see the updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the manual for [$or operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/), you don't need `conditions` before it. For example in [mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/):

```js
db.chats.find(
              {$or:[
                    {'sender_id': "55505ad6b5a0925f4c8b7707"}, 
                    {'receivers_id':{ $elemMatch:{ $eq:"55505ad6b5a0925f4c8b7707" } } }
                   ], 
              'messages.sender':{ $ne:"55505ad6b5a0925f4c8b7707" }
              }
)
```

You could utilise [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) using combination of [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/), [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/). For example, to match and unwind :

```js
db.chats.aggregate([
                  {$match: 
                       {$or:[
                             {'sender_id': 1}, 
                             {'receivers_id':{
                                        $elemMatch:{$eq:1}}}], 'messages.sender':{$ne:1}}}, 
                 {$unwind:"$messages"}, 
                 {$unwind:"$messages.read_by"}
])
```

Once you have the result, you could group and sum accordingly. (unfortunately, Your example doesn't show how unread was detected, and there's only 1 message)

Having said that, you need to re-consider your [data models](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/data-modeling/). Having messages stored in an embedded documents, may reach the [BSON document size limit of 16MB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#bson-documents) once you have many messages. Your current model may be suitable for small chats, but it won't scale well. See [Data Model Examples and Patterns](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models/) for more information.

Comment: i will reconsider data models